# Codename One reverse an InfiniteContainer / InfiniteScrollAdapter

Tags: codenameone

I need a reverse InfiniteContainer - scroll upward to load more. **Similar to the WhatsApp message view**.

What way would I need to modify an InfiniteContainer / InfiniteScrollAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can or should modify `InfiniteContainer`. Just use a regular container and scroll it to the bottom.

To fetch additional elements you can use a scroll listener to monitor scroll position and add elements to the top when the user reaches that location.